# Stream Instead of Byte[]

Tags: c#, wcf, basichttpbinding

I'm building simple WCF to stream a file to Android (using Xamarin.Android). For that, i configured the service as BasicHttpBinding, and used the `TransferMode=Streamed`. For a easy test, i'm using a simple WPF application to test the service, before i deploy it to Android.

The first problem i'd faced is:
- If i include the service in WPF as *Service Reference*, i still need to configure the client binding on client side. But on server side there's a client configuration too. So, why he doesn't bring me the configuration from server ?
This is the WebConfig of server:

```
<client>
  <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingStreamed"
    contract="Web_Explorer.IWeb_Explorer" name="" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
</client>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingStreamed" maxBufferSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
      transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Text" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="Web_Explorer.WExplorer">
    <endpoint address="Explorer" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingStreamed"
      name="basicHttp" contract="Web_Explorer.IWeb_Explorer" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I resolved that by configuring the client side. Everything ok.

After that i added the service in my WPF app as Web Service (the only option available in Xamarin.Android). The problem now is:
- One of my classes returns a `Stream` type. After i changed to a WebReference, the return isn't a `Stream` anymore, but a `byte[]` (in client side). I have read that works, but my question is, why he changed the return type ? And from the researches that i did, if i use the `byte[]` as return, i must wait the upload to be completed to work with it, right ?
Code:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IWeb_Explorer
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream LeArquivo();
}



public Stream LeArquivo()
    {
        Expl.sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Viagens3.xml").BaseStream;
        return Expl.sr;
    }
```

I probably wrote a lot of meaningless things here. But i just can't learn WCF. This thing doesn't enter in my head.

Comment: So the underlying question is: "What is the Correct way to stream a large file (or content) to an android client from a WCF service?"

Comment: This is my final objective. But i wanna know what i'm doing. Why the return type is changing ?